# How to solve 'Next without For' error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am receiving a **next without for** error from:

```
Sub CTLines()
Dim iVal As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
    
Set ws1 = Worksheets("INCIDENTS")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("INCDB")
    
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AO5:AO999"), "Yes")
    
Dim i
    
For i = 1 To iVal
    With Sheets("INCDB")
        .Range("5:5").Insert Shift:=x1Down
Next i
End Sub
```

I've tried changing the variable, the indent, many things and I've not been successful.

All I want to do is to count how many rows contain `Yes` in the AO column and add as many rows in the INCDB spreadsheet.

Comment: you need a end with statement

Comment: And you need to use `xlDown`, not `x1Down`. The letter "l" as in "lambda".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the code to this, near the bottom:

```
For i = 1 To iVal
    With Sheets("INCDB")
        .Range("5:5").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
Next i
```

The VBA compiler is not good at reporting what is wrong, when it encounters code that has one or more lines that are missing a matching termination line.

In your case you never terminated the `With` statement.

Comment: @eirikdaude  It was not obvious to Ugo and the comment was NOT there when I answered.

Comment: The timestamps indicate otherwise. Anyway I am just stating why some people may have given you downvotes.

Comment: @eirikdaude I see what you mean, but all I can say is that the comment was not there when I answered. At any rate, it is the correct answer and is not deserving of down-votes.

Comment: one thing, @ExcelHero, when I create the lines they're pulling the formatting from the row above. Is there a way to remove it?