# Compile error: End with without with. BUT THE WITH IS THERE

Tags: vba, excel

To my working code, I had to ad a new `With` `EndWith`. No I can't run it anymore and the second `EndWith` causes the Error. Compile error: End with without with. I tried as well to do e nested `With` `EndWith`, it didn't work. Any idea? Thanks for any help!

This is the required part of the code:

```
 With wsSrc
        LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        For j = 0 To UBound(SearchValues)
            For i = 2 To LastRow
                If .Cells(i, 1).Value = SearchValues(j) Then

                    wsDest.Range("A" & z).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
                    wsDest.Range("B" & z).Value = .Range("N" & i).Value
                    wsDest.Range("C" & z).Value = .Range("O" & i).Value
                    wsDest.Range("D" & z).Value = .Range("AM" & i).Value
                    wsDest.Range("G" & z).Value = .Range("AH" & i).Value
                    wsDest.Range("I" & z).Value = .Range("P" & i).Value
                    wsDest.Range("J" & z).Value = .Range("E" & i).Value
                    wsDest.Range("K" & z).Value = .Range("F" & i).Value

                    z = z + 1

                End If
            Next i
        Next j
   End With
    With wsSrc2
        LastRow2 = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            For k = 2 To LastRow2
                If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "724" Then
                    wsDest.Range("B" & z).Value = .Range("N" & k).Value
                    wsDest.Range("C" & z).Value = .Range("O" & k).Value
                    wsDest.Range("D" & z).Value = .Range("AM" & k).Value
                    wsDest.Range("G" & z).Value = .Range("T" & k).Value
                    wsDest.Range("I" & z).Value = .Range("P" & k).Value
                    wsDest.Range("J" & z).Value = .Range("E" & k).Value
                    wsDest.Range("K" & z).Value = .Range("F" & k).Value
                    wsDest.Range("A" & z).Value = "724"
                    z = z + 1
                End If
    End With
```

Comment: You are missing a `Next` in your `For k = 2` logic! Sometimes error messages are not always what they seem!

Comment: This question is about pretty much the same thing: [Next without for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286860/next-without-for)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve 'Next without For' error in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286860/how-to-solve-next-without-for-error-in-vba)

Answer (score 1):

Your next is missing on the bottom For Loop